# Isomorphism map between $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^2+x+2)}$ and $ \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^2 + 1)} $

Tags: field-theory, vector-space-isomorphism

$\frac{\mathbb{F}_3[x]}{(x^2+x+2)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{F}_3[x]}{(x^2 + 1)} $

I know $\frac{\mathbb{F}_3[x]}{(x^2+x+2)} $ and $ \frac{\mathbb{F}_3[x]}{(x^2 + 1)} $ is isomorphic because they are both 2-degree extension of $ \mathbb{F}_3 $ .

But I cannot contract explicit isomorphism between them.

> Could you show me isomorphism map between $\frac{\mathbb{F}_3[x]}{(x^2+x+2)}$  and $ \frac{\mathbb{F}_3[x]}{(x^2 + 1)} $?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try $\phi:\mathbb{F}_3[X]\to\mathbb{F}_3[X]$ defined by $\phi:X\mapsto X+1$ whilst leaving everything in $\mathbb{F}_3$ alone.

This sends $X^2+X+2$ to $X^2+1$, so it sends the ideal $(X^2+X+2)$ to the ideal $(X^2+1)$, so when you quotient out $\mathbb{F}_3[X]$ by $(X^2+X+2)$ or by $(X^2+1)$, you get isomorphic fields.

Comment: Thank you so much, but sorry, ①why X→X＋1 sends X^2＋X＋2 to X^2＋1?② How did you find that? ③what about F5[x]/（x^2-2）and F5[x]/（x^2＋x＋1）? Sorry to ask there questions...Thank you.

Comment: @bellow So, $\phi:X\mapsto X+1$ means that it will send $X^2+X+2$ to $(X+1)^2+(X+1)+2=X^2+2X+1+X+1+2=X^2+1$. Don't expect this map to work for all $\mathbb{F}_p$, it works for $\mathbb{F}_3$ but does not necessarily work for others.

Comment: Thank you , about question ③, translation didn't apply.What kind of change of variable is  effective?

Comment: @bellow So if you tried a few maps like $X\mapsto aX+b$ you'll notice that none of them work. It looks like you might have to try ones that look like $X\mapsto aX^2+bX+c$ (or even higher degrees). Of course, you have to be careful that they are well-defined maps between $\mathbb{F}_5[X]\to\mathbb{F}_5[X]$, so there's quite a bit of calculating and checking to do.

Comment: but constant term do not vanish...