# isomorphism between $\frac{\mathbb{F}_5[x]}{(x^2+x+1)} $ and $ \frac{\mathbb{F}_5[x]}{(x^2 -2)} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

I know $\frac{\mathbb{F}_5[x]}{(x^2+x+1)} $ and $ \frac{\mathbb{F}_5[x]}{(x^2 -2)} $ is isomorphic because they are both 2-degree extension of $ \mathbb{F}_5 $ .

But I cannot contract explicit isomorphism between them.

> Could you show me isomorphism map between $\frac{\mathbb{F}_5[x]}{(x^2+x+1)}$  and $ \frac{\mathbb{F}_5[x]}{(x^2 - 2)} $?

I tried to show $$
f\colon\mathbb{F}_5[x]\to\mathbb{F}_5[x]/(x^2+x＋1)$$ is isomorphism,  which sends $x$ to $g(x)＋c＋(x^2＋x-1)$. I couldn't find $g(x)$, and show $f$ is ring hom and bijection（surjection is clear）. I couldn't find $g(x)$ because constant term doesn't vanish. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you set $y=2x+1$ in $\mathbb F_5[x]/\left(x^2+x+1\right),$ I think $y^2=2.$ This gives some mapping between them.

Comment: I believe there is an automorphism of $F_5$ which sends $x^2 + x + 1 \mapsto x^2 - 2$. This would induce an isomorphism of their quotients.

Comment: I couldn't find that because constant term doesn't vanish...

Comment: Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012411/isomorphism-map-between-frac-mathbbz-3xx2x2-and-frac-mathbb) from four hours ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, I outline the isomorphism. If we fix $y:=2x+1\in\mathbb F_5[x]/\left(x^2+x+1\right),$ then we see that
$$y^2=4x^2+4x+1=2.$$
In particular, we can construct a map
$$\mathbb F_5[y]\to\frac{\mathbb F_5[x]}{(x^2+x+1)}$$
by sending $y\mapsto2x+1.$ It's not difficult to check that this is surjective, for $3y+2\mapsto x.$ It remains to show that our kernel is $\left(y^2-2\right).$ The kernel requires $p(y)\in\mathbb F_5[y]$ to have
$$p(2x+1)\equiv0\pmod{x^2+x+1}.$$
However, this is equivalent to
$$p(2x+1)\equiv0\pmod{(2x+1)^2-2},$$
so indeed $p(y)\in\left(y^2-2\right).$ This finishes the construction of our isomorphism.

At a high level, we were looking for an automorphism of $\mathbb F_{5^2},$ so it makes sense to look for linear maps to do the trick. This is what motivates the $y:=2x+1$ substitution.

Comment: Thank you ! Why the map is ring how?